# Issue of reset value assignment in the UVM register model

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I came across a register model example as below. Register `ureg1_t` looks like:

[image]

```
class ureg1_t extends uvm_reg;

  rand uvm_reg_field destination;
  rand uvm_reg_field frame_kind;
  rand uvm_reg_field rsvd;

  virtual function void build();
    destination = uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("destination");
    destination.configure(this, 14, 0, "RW", 0, 32'h12345678>>0, 1, 1, 1);
    frame_kind = uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("frame_kind");
    frame_kind.configure(this, 2, 14, "RW", 0, 32'h12345678>>14, 1, 1, 1);
    rsvd = uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("rsvd");
    rsvd.configure(this, 16, 16, "RW", 0, 32'h12345678>>16, 1, 1, 1);
    uvm_pkg::uvm_resource_db#(bit)::set({"REG::",get_full_name()}, "NO_REG_ACCESS_TEST", 1);
  endfunction
```

Where:

`destination`'s reset value is `32'h12345678>>0`

`frame_kind`'s reset value is `32'h12345678>>14`

`rsvd`'s reset value is `32'h12345678>>16`

I'm confused that `destination`'s 14 bits, `frame_kind`'s 2 bits and `rsvd`'s 16 bits can't be represented by `32'h12345678>>0`, `32'h12345678>>14` and `32'h12345678>>16` I think.

Could you guide me the way of assignment a reset value in register model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use numeric constants of the required bit widths for the reset values.  For example, you declare the `destination` field bit width as 14 (the 2nd argument to `configure` is the field `size`, and you set it to 14).  However, you then set its reset to a 32-bit value: `32'h12345678>>0` resolves to `32'h12345678`.  You should set it to the 14-bit value `14'h1678`.  Do the same for all fields.

```
  virtual function void build();
    destination = uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("destination");
    destination.configure(this, 14, 0, "RW", 0, 14'h1678, 1, 1, 1);
    frame_kind = uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("frame_kind");
    frame_kind.configure(this, 2, 14, "RW", 0, 2'h1, 1, 1, 1);
    rsvd = uvm_reg_field::type_id::create("rsvd");
    rsvd.configure(this, 16, 16, "RW", 0, 16'h1234, 1, 1, 1);
    uvm_pkg::uvm_resource_db#(bit)::set({"REG::",get_full_name()}, "NO_REG_ACCESS_TEST", 1);
  endfunction
```